# Easy ui 1.3.5 - dialog with datagrid inside not loading

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I have the following problem ...

I'm using Easy-ui v 1.3.5. Everything is working fine, but I have a weird problem. I have a datagrid that  has a column that acts as a "view detail" button. This is a plain "img" element with an onclick handler. The idea is that when a user clicks this button, the app shows a modal dialog that contains a datagrid that contains the detail related to the clicked row.

It works fine except THE FIRST TIME (and only the first time) the user clicks this button, the datagrid inside the dialog is not being rendered. It just shows the column header names, with no format.

The dialog is a div:

```
<div id="dlg-div" style="background-color: #F0F0F0;"></div>
```

This is the function to open the dialog:

```
function viewDialog(id)
{
    /*load some params and stuff*/
    $('#dlg-div').dialog({
            title: 'Some title',
            width: someValue,
            height: someValue,
            closed: false,
            cache: false,
            href: 'detail_url',
            modal: true
        });
}
```

The detail url_contains the following:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            /*load some valus*/
            $('#dataRegistroBloqueoAgenciasDetalle').datagrid({
                queryParams: 
                {
                    someName: someValue
                },
                onLoadSuccess: f1,
                onLoadError: f2,
                onSortColumn: f3,
                singleSelect: false, 
                title: 'some title',
                loadMsg : 'wait...',
                pagination: true,
                striped: true,
                pageSize: 50,
                pageList:[50],
                url: '${a_url}',
                nowrap: true,
                remoteSort: false
            });
        });
    </script>

<div id="layout-detalle-bloqueo-agencias-center" style='width: 90%; padding: 10px;'>
            <table  id="dataRegistroBloqueoAgenciasDetalle">
                <thead>
                    <c:forEach var="headDetalle" items="${encabezadoDetalle}"> 
                        <c:if test="${headDetalle.properties.integer == true}">
                            <th data-options="field:'${headDetalle.properties.id}', width: 180, halign:'center', align:'right', formatter: formatNumber, sortable: true">${headDetalle.title}</th>
                        </c:if>   
                        <c:if test="${headDetalle.properties.integer != true}">
                            <th data-options="field:'${headDetalle.properties.id}', width: 180, halign:'center', align:'center', sortable: true">${headDetalle.title}</th>
                        </c:if>          
                    </c:forEach>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <!-- json to load table body, via post -->
                </tbody>
            </table>                      
        </div>
```

The datagrid loads the table body with a post to another servlet. The JSON response is correct.

Firefox, chrome and explorer do not show any kind of javascript or network error. I have searched in forums and other places but I haven't found any info on this bug (if it is a bug). My questions are:

1. Does anyone know something about this problem or something similar related to easy ui?
2. Im using java EE6 on the server side (jboss eap 6.2). Could this be a problem related to the servlet initialization? The first request forces the container to initialize the server and for some unknown reason this prevents the datagrid rendering only one time.

Kind regards!

Comment: i keep working on this and i noticed that this only happens when im  using a vpn...ill take a look at the traffic and keep updating the post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, its solved. The problem was between my vpn and my server...